# Is this set theory proof valid?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Question is:

$\forall$ Sets $A, B, C$ , If $A - (B \cap C)$ = $\emptyset$, then $(A - C)\subset B$

I know this question is True, here is my proof.

Let $A , B, C$ be sets

Assume $A - (B \cap C) = \emptyset$. I will prove $A - C \subset B$. Let $x \in (A-C)$. Then, $x \in A, x \notin C$. I will prove $x \in B$ by contradiction.

Suppose $x \notin B$.

Since $A - (B\cap C) = \emptyset$, $\forall x\in A,x \in (B\cap C)$

Then, since $x \in (B \cap C)$, $x \in B$, and  $x \in C$. Since we assumed $x \notin B$, $x\notin C$, we have proof by contradiction that $x \in B$.

Comment: The last step might be easier to follow if it were: if $x \not \in B$ then $x \not (B\cap C)$ and $x \in A$ so $x\in A-(B\cap C)$ but that's a contradiction as $A- (B\cap C)$ is empty.  ... or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is okay, your formulation in the last part is just a little bit strange.

Suggestion: Suppose $x\notin B$. Then $x\notin B\cap C$ and hence $x\in A-(B\cap C)$. But $A-(B\cap C)=\emptyset$ so we have proof by contradiction that $x\in B$.

**EDIT:** Now I got the spare time to explain your mistakes. You wrote

> Since $A - (B\cap C) = \emptyset$, $\forall x\in A,x \in (B\cap C)$

Two problems: First, you already used the variable $x$ before, so this is highly confusing. Second, even if you used $y$ instead, the comma "$,$" is still irritating. It looks like you wanted to write

> Since $A - (B\cap C) = \emptyset$, we have $\forall y\in A : y \in (B\cap C)$

i.e. any element in $A$ must also be in $B\cap C$. Let's move on.

> Then, since $x \in (B \cap C)$, $x \in B$, and  $x \in C$

again, it is unclear what your $x$ is. **Why is $x\in B\cap C$?** Are you referring to

> Then, $x \in A, x \notin C$.

? Then this would be okay, but because of your "$\forall x$" notation earlier, this is very unclear.

Finally, you make a technical mistake in your proof. You assumed $x\in A - C$ and followed that $x\in C$. You already reached a contradiction! But not in the sense of "proof by contradiction", but you showed that $A-C$ is the empty set! Assuming at one point that $x\notin B$ is pointless, because you showed that such an $x$ does not exist. So concluding that $x\in B$ by "proof by contradiction" is highly invalid!

But luckily for you, since $A-C=\emptyset$ and $\emptyset\subseteq D$ for any set $D$, you can still conclude that $A-C\subseteq B$. with your approach.

Comment: Thats what the answer did as well! I just did it my way and was wondering if on a test i would get docked marks because of invalid logic. That is a way more clear way of putting it for sure.

Comment: @MattyS11 Yes, there is invalid logic. Now I have taken the time to point it out. Thanks for the early answer acceptance anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

From the premise, A subset B $\cup$ C.
Now remove C from both sides and the
desired conclusion quickly follows.